# Orocommerce bundle theme not found on build or admin webpanel

Tags: php, symfony, orocommerce

I have multiple failed intent to create a bundle without successfully result.

First I install orocommerce like information on *https://doc.oroinc.com/4.1/backend/setup/dev-environment/*
(fork project on *https://github.com/juankav89/orocommerce-application*, execute **composer install --prefer-dist** and **php bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=2000**

Next one I create bundle folders and files and when try to activate a bundle, show me next result (first excecute clear cache command and next excecute **php bin/console oro:assets:build bogota**):

```
Building assets.
'/usr/local/bin/node' './node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js' '--hide-modules' '--env.theme=my_theme' '--env.stats=' '--env.symfony=dev' '--colors'
/home/juan/atlantictSoft/orocommerce/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Theme "my_theme" doesn't exists. Existing themes:admin.demo, admin.oro, blank, embedded_default, default, custom, view-switcher
```

When I try to install a bundle (with **php bin/console oro:assets:install** command), not show me errors, but not include bundle on **php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.bundles --format=json** result.

Next I include structure of my bundle:

```
orocommerce
...
├── src
│   ├── AppCache.php
│   ├── AppKernel.php
│   ├── Bogota
│   │   └── Bundle
│   │       └── NewBundle
│   │           ├── BogotaNewBundle.php
│   │           └── Resources
│   │               └── config
│   │                   └── oro
│   │                       └── bundles.yml
│   ├── MedellinBundle
│   │   └── Resources
│   │       ├── public
│   │       │   └── images
│   │       │       ├── descarga.png:Zone.Identifier
│   │       │       └── logo.png
│   │       └── views
│   │           └── layouts
│   │               └── first_theme
│   │                   └── theme.yml
│   └── teste
│       └── Bundle
│           └── TesteBundle
│               ├── Resources
│               │   ├── config
│               │   │   └── teste
│               │   │       ├── bundles.yml
│               │   │       └── bundles.yml:Zone.Identifier
│               │   ├── public
│               │   │   └── theme
│               │   │       ├── favicons
│               │   │       │   ├── favicon.ico
│               │   │       │   └── favicon.ico:Zone.Identifier
│               │   │       ├── images
│               │   │       │   ├── logo.svg
│               │   │       │   └── logo.svg:Zone.Identifier
│               │   │       └── scss
│               │   │           ├── components
│               │   │           │   ├── top-bar.scss
│               │   │           │   └── top-bar.scss:Zone.Identifier
│               │   │           ├── settings
│               │   │           │   ├── _colors.scss
│               │   │           │   ├── _colors.scss:Zone.Identifier
│               │   │           ├── styles.scss
│               │   │           ├── styles.scss:Zone.Identifier
│               │   │           └── variables
│               │   │               ├── top-bar-config.scss
│               │   │               └── top-bar-config.scss:Zone.Identifier
│               │   └── views
│               │       └── layouts
│               │           └── theme
│               │               ├── config
│               │               │   ├── assets.yml
│               │               │   └── assets.yml:Zone.Identifier
│               │               ├── theme.yml
│               │               └── theme.
```

I Verify that namespaces and names of files does correctly definition; ex **Bogota Bundle**:

*src/Bogota/Bundle/NewBundle/Resources/config/oro/bundles.yml*

```
bundles:
    - Bogota\Bundle\NewBundle\BogotaNewBundle
```

*src/Bogota/Bundle/NewBundle/BogotaNewBundle.php*

```
<?php
namespace Bogota\Bundle\NewBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class BogotaNewBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Finally I try to check  "http://localhost/app_dev.php/" but return 4040 and **http://localhost/admin/config/system on Configuration->Commerce->Desing->Theme ** but not show custom bundles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that only correct bundle definition in the provided structure is **BogotaNewBundle**. The definitions done in it
are correct and it will register bundle in application succesfully.

**MedellinBundle** item is not a Symfony bundle and as for Oro's theme it relies on a bundle and must be defined inside of it.

---

It's recommended to learn next https://doc.oroinc.com/master/frontend/storefront/quick-start article's content a bit precisely and then all other topics in https://doc.oroinc.com/master/frontend/storefront

---

Here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HNv_m2rBRIYj0UW6HNpoGcDygzz6wvW4/view?usp=sharing) to simple working bundle's archive with proper theme definitions.

!!!Note **src/Bogota/Bundle/NewBundle/Resources/views/layouts/first_theme** folder. **first_theme** is the theme's name and it must be used with **php bin/console oro:assets:build** command if you want to run build only for it. Also this command expects assets to be installed into **public** folder with **php bin/console oro:assets:install** command before. Running **oro:assets:install** includes build routines.